# Compare nested lists in python and output the missing item in the list

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I am trying to compare a list of names that each contain a list of fruits and output the fruit that is missing.

Below is code snippet from the original script.  I basically create a list of names and a list of fruits, then I append the fruit list to the name list.

In python how can be compare the fruit lists for each name?

**Code snippet**

```
namelist = []
namelist.append(users_row[7])
fruitlist = []
fruitlist.append(users_row[4])
namelist.append((list(fruitlist), fruitlist))
print(fruitlist)
```

**Current Output**

```
['John', ([['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes']])]
['Amy', ([['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes', 'Mango']])]
['Peter', ([['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes']])]
```

**Required Output**

```
John,Mango
Amy
Peter,Pear,Mango
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `list-comprehension`:

Assuming there is a `master_lst` which is the one we would compare with our desired lists:

```
master_lst = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes', 'Mango']

johns_lst = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes']
amys_lst = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes', 'Mango']
peters_lst = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes']

print([x for x in master_lst if x not in johns_lst])
print([x for x in master_lst if x not in amys_lst])
print([x for x in master_lst if x not in peters_lst])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['Mango']                                                                                                                                                                    
[]                                                                                                                                                                           
['Pear', 'Mango']
```

To depict the desired output:

```
print("John,", ",".join([x for x in master_lst if x not in johns_lst]))
print("Amy,", ",".join([x for x in master_lst if x not in amys_lst]))
print("Peter,", ",".join([x for x in master_lst if x not in peters_lst]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
John, Mango                                                                                                                                                                  
Amy,                                                                                                                                                                         
Peter, Pear,Mango
```